# Mongo docker image not persisting user creation

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build my own mongo docker image. After installing mongo in the build process, I also want to add few pre-seeded users.

```
db = db = db.getSiblingDB("<dbname>");

db.createUser(
   {
     user: "<username>",
     pwd: "<password>",
     roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "<dbname>" } ]
   }
)
```

Once the image is built , I spin up a container and "use" correct db , I do not see the users created  --

> db.getUsers()
>   [ ]

I have read the article [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) , which suggests to create ephemeral containers but does not necessary claim that they are indeed ephemeral.

Any insight would help.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you from vast experience with Mongo and Docker (or any database for that matter); that is is better not to make an image with a database embedded.

It can be done but one some platforms you can lose a lot of time getting it up to speed.

> Recommendation:  Keep you code and database on separate servers and
>   bake in the DB credentials in your Docker image.

Host DB for free here https://mlab.com/

This is just my opinion please take many opinions and formulate your own.  More reading here: https://vsupalov.com/database-in-docker/

Comment: Thanks Nelles. Would you explain a bit further when you said -- "bake in the DB credentials in your Docker image" . I thought I am trying to achieve the same.

Comment: @Rajesh what I meant to say is rather than have the mongo credentials say <localhost> refer it to another server <someIpAddres>.  The idea being create your Docker image with the Database only the credentials.  I have learned that what ever size project there are a ton of advantages to keeping the DB on a separate server.  For example let AWS or mlab manage your data (they have redundant backups etc.)